# Is there a screensaver that makes my computer look unlocked?

Tags: windows-7, screensaver

Due to office shenanigans, I try to leave my computer locked when I step away. Sometimes I forget and hilarity ensues.

What I'd like, though, is a way to detect when attempted shenanigans occur. That is, I'd like my screensaver to simply look like an unlocked computer but change in some way when it's disturbed. It doesn't need to be overly convincing--just a simple freeze until touched is fine.

Anything like that out there?

Comment: While on the subject, however a little off topic, I thought you might like this official [Blue Screen of Death](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897558.aspx) screensaver straight from Microsoft's TechNet site.

Comment: @Brian, oh yes, we've had much fun with that

Comment: you could always try a motion detector camera, and have it make a loud noise when it detects them :P

Answer (score 6):

1. Google "picture screensaver"
2. Find a screen saver that lets you decide what pictures it displays
3. Take a screenshot of your desktop, when shenanigans are tried it will ask for password

Comment: I think you might be able to do this by using the already installed "My Picture Slideshow" if you choose a directory that just has your screenshot, set "how often" to less, set how big to %100, and turn off transitions. It might flash every few minutes but would unlikely be noticed by someone in a hurry to mess with you.